# method chain hijacking

Tags: php

This isn't a *real* fluent interface. I have an object which builds up a method stack. Which gets executed by a single function call. But now I might add another virtual method, which "takes over" that method stack.

---

Use case: I'm wrapping my superglobals into objects. This allows me to "enforce" input filtering. $_GET and co provide simple sanitizing methods. And my new version now allows chaining of atomic filters. As example:

```
$_GET->ascii->nocontrol->text["field"]
```

This is a method call. It uses angle brackets. But that's just a nice trick which eases rewriting any occourence of `$_GET["field"]`. Anyway.

Now there are also occasionally forms with enumerated fields, as in field[0],field[1],field[2]. That's why I've added a virtual ->array filter method. It hijacks the collected method stack, and iterates the remaining filters on e.g. a $_POST array value. For example `$_POST->array->int["list"]`.

Somewhat shortened implementation:

```
function exec_chain ($data) {
    ...
    while ($filtername = array_pop($this->__filter)) {
    ...
        $data = $this->{"_$filtername"} ($data);
    ...
}

function _array($data) {
    list($multiplex, $this->__filter) = array($this->__filter, array());
    $data = (array) $data;
    foreach (array_keys($data) as $i) {
        $this->__filter = $multiplex;
        $data[$i] = $this->exec_chain($data[$i]);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The method stack gets assembled in the `$this->__filter` list. Above exec_chain() just loops over it, each time removing the first method name. The virtual _array handler is usually the first method. And it simply steals that method stack, and reexecutes the remainder on each array element. Not exactly like in above example code, but it just repeatedly repopulates the original method stack.

It works. But it feels kind of unclean. And I'm thinking of adding another virtual method `->xor`. (YAGNI?) Which would not just iterate over fields, but rather evaluate if alternate filters were successful. For example `$_REQUEST->array->xor->email->url["fields"]`. And I'm wondering if there is a better pattern for hijacking a function list. My current hook list ($this->__filter) swapping doesn't lend itself to chaining. Hmm well actually, the ->xor example wouldn't need to iterate / behave exactly like ->array.

So specifically, I'm interested in finding an alternative to my $this->__filter list usage with array_pop() and the sneaky swapping it out. This is bad. Is there a better implementation scheme to executing a method list half part me -> half part you?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  It's also hard not to knee-jerk react to the "fluent interface" and suggest that you do something else (!) even though you made it clear that you're not asking about that part.

Comment: Gah, damned enter-to-submit-but-only-in-comment-boxes bites me again....  Can you expand on the use case where you think that you need something smarter.  From what I can tell of the code you pasted, you've got something that does what you want, and it isn't too terrible--I object more to the fluent interface-ness than the implementation.

Comment: Well, it works. But the hooklist-hotswapping seems really dirty. And objectively it's just a featuritis question, not sure if I really need the new virtal method. It's something that could be handled by the application logic, it only feels like belonging into the input handler. Anyway, should I need the ->xor or some other new feature I certainly need to get rid of the concurrent array manipulation. That's the main point of my question.

Comment: My fluent interface note, btw. I was saying that this isn't actually a fluent interface. The methods don't really chain. It's basically catching property accesses which lead to building up my $__filter chain method stack. A fun side effect: if I first write a non-statement like `$_GET->name->text;` it'll save a filter chain, and it get's applied first if I access `$_GET["field"]`. Reminds me of a jQuery plugin I've recently written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a similar chaining interface before, I like your idea of using it on GET/POST vars.

I think you will be better off doing something like

```
$var->array->email_XOR_url;
```

rather than

```
$var->array->email->XOR->url;
```

. That way you can catch the various combinations with your __get/__call magic.

Comment: Not what I wanted. But instead of complicating my code any further, I'll take this approach. Managing this feature in __call is definitely simpler than adding another workaround. Or I might even try a simple `->xor(var, filter1, filter2, filter3)` method.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like it either. Using $var->array->xor('email','url') seems like the best option.

Comment: Actually, I think you should get rid of the array filter, since it's always at position 1. Just flip a switch in the constructor instead. If the switch is on then any chains will be applied to each array member.

Comment: I'd vote for the xor()-as-a-function approach, having used it a lot myself in the past.